# ¿Cómo recorrer un Json con java?

Tags: java, json

Tengo este json y quiero recorrerlo y obtener los elementos "name".

```
{
   "lstOfficialDocuments":[
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNN001 CREDENCIAL ELECTORS",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNS002 PASAPORTE",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNS003 CARTILLA",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNS004 CEDULA PROFESIONAL",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNN017 TUIM",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNS052 DRIVER LICENSE",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNS060 RESIDENT ALIEN CARD",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNS062 MATRICULA CONSULAR",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNN066 TARJETA DE INAPAM",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SSS070 ID.AMERICANO VEHI M",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SSS072 LICENCIA CONDUCIR",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNN092 CREDENCIAL DEL IMSS",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNN248 LICEN COND PERM",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNN249 CRED ELECT RES EXT",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNN254 TARJETA RESIDENTE",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNN648 CREDENCIAL ISSSTE",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNN649 CRED SEGURO POPULAR",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      },
      {
         "document":{
            "name":"SNN775 CREDENCIAL ISSFA",
            "firstPage":false,
            "lastPage":false
         },
         "totalDocuments":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero recibes el `JSONObject`, luego debes obtener el `JSONArray` llamado **"lstOfficialDocuments"** y por ultimo recorres sus pociones obteniendo la clave "name":

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("MyJSON");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("lstOfficialDocuments");
CargarArray(jsonArray);


public void CargarArray(JSONArray jsonArray){
ArrayList<String> Lista = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        try {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //Aquí se obtiene el dato y es guardado en una lista
            Lista.add(json.getString("name"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**PD:** Recuerda que los `"{}"` son Objectos y los `"[]"` son Arrays, mientras tengas eso en mente se hace mas fácil entenderlo.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List obtenerNombres(JSONArray json){
    JSONArray documentos = json["lstOfficialDocuments"];
    List nombres = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i < documentos.length(); i++){
       nombres.add(documentos[i]["name"]);
    }
 return nombres;
}
```

Puedes obtener más información sobre trabajo con JSON [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON).